# How do I calculate the parabola of a molotov with only angle and distance?

Tags: physics, conic-sections, angle

I am playing a game where you can shoot a molotov. My goal is to be able to choose a distance I want the molotov to land (from the player) and get an angle to aim to reach that, the game has no information about gravity, resistance, velocity etc so calculating it with physics is not possible, however all of the previously mentioned variables are constant.

Currently, I am aiming up to the sky as much as is allowed then slowly moving my mouse to look down/forward, I then record my mouse movement to get the angle. My screen height is 1080 pixels do I can get angle with `a = (pixels_down/1080)*90`.

My first approach was just finding a fixed value and doing a calculation, my first one was `angle_to_aim = desired_distance*5.2`, which worked ok, but failed past or before a certain range.

I also tried linear regression, but it didn't work because it's a parabola.

My question is, if I gather a bunch of data, how can I calculate the parabola or predict where the molotov will land? Here is a little bit of data I have gathered thus far:

[image: graph]
0-78 pixels always results in 0 meters (straight back down)

Comment: Could you add a picture to show how the angle is computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your "number of pixel" $p$ is proportional to $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between initial velocity and ground. Moreover, I'll assume your projectile is launched from negligible height.

If so, the formula for the [range of a projectile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile) can be written as:
$$
d=kp\sqrt{m-p^2},
$$
where $k$ and $m$ are two constants to be determined.

One can use two of your lines of data to find them: taking the first and penultimate line (the last one looks a bit off) I got:
$$
k\approx 0.000361126,\quad m\approx 278922
$$
which gives results in fair agreement with the other data.

Comment: This does seem to give good data up to about 300 pixels, but it breaks down after that. I collected some new data after my original post. 475 is about the limit to where aiming down gives more height. (which is near 45 degrees so I suppose it makes sense).

See [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_IDRbuv0SE13qw4iKDvz6mQ7oN2LOLB9aFcAMhWPrM/edit?usp=sharing) with pixels, real distance, prediction etc.

Comment: A more refined result could be obtained by a fit to all data. But one should be sure about the meaning of your pixel measure: could you explain more or include a picture? Moreover: am I correct in thinking the molotov starts from ground level?

Comment: Sure, I can try explain. The game is a first person shooter, so you look in first person (of course), I get the pixel measurement by looking up towards the sky as much as possible, then lowering my mouse making me face downwards more, then recording the amount of pixels down I go. Sorry if that's not very concise, but 0 pixels would be looking directly up, and 1080 directly down (because that's my monitor size), then 540 would be looking dead on. The character is standing on flat ground and it lands on the same elevation.

Comment: Is that accurate? I mean: if you repeat a shooting with $p=110$, do you always get $d=20$? And then, does the molotov start from ground or not? If not, is its starting height significant, compared to distance $d$?

Comment: It starts from the eyes, (I assume?) it would be a height of 1m maximum. The results are always the same, yes.

Comment: But, above all, we have no guarantee the author of the game followed a physical model: he might have used some fancy equation. And we cannot exclude some "noise" is added at random.

Comment: I am very sure no noise is added, thats an intrinsic part of the game. However, yes, we can't know if it's an actual physical model.

Comment: I don't understand: is $p=1080$ shooting parallel to the ground or down to your feet?

Comment: Down to your feet, 1080 is looking down as much as possible and 0 is looking up as much as possible. I made a little Python script to try bruteforce the best K and M and found 0.0025 and 536700 to be very accurate, with an average error of 0.52, definitely possible my recording was just wrong and those are the real numbers. Great result. Thanks a lot.